# Using Selenium to download .csv files from webpages

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm trying to use Selenium and Java to download .csv files and then re-upload them. The program would visit a google doc with a list of urls. It would then visit each of these urls and click a hyperlink on each site to download a .csv file. It would then go to Google Drive and re-upload the .csv files as google spreadsheets.

Is this possible to accomplish with Selenium? If not, what is a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is a library that interacts with a browser's [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). It sounds like you are going to be doing **none** of that. You will be interacting with the local filesystem (**not** a browser DOM), accessing web links (very little to do with browser DOM), and reading .csv files (**not** a browser DOM).

You want to use Java and [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/).